# Why is i.histo.match missing from QGIS 3.x?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, grass-gis, qgis-processing, histogram

I'm trying to normalise and then mosaic two ASTER scenes (multiple bands in each). The GRASS tool i.histo.match has been suggested in a few places, but it isn't listed in the processing toolbox for QGIS 3.x

https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/addons/i.histo.match.html

Can anyone advise how to have this script added to the GRASS tools of QGIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to one of the original developers (Luca Delucchi), i.histo.match is an addon module (python script) and so has never been included as a plugin within QGIS.

However, it would be a good addition to the QGIS toolkit, as a way to balance remote sensing rasters (ASTER, Landsat, etc etc) before performing a mosaic.